# Are regular expression adequate for analyzing large text?

Tags: c++, regex, parsing

I have a text of about ~1000000 words (just an example) and I want to parse it in just **one iteration**. And what I want to do is every time an expression is matched, change it for something else. For example:

The expressions:

```
| Expression     | New text |
|----------------|----------|
| ab             | A        |
| #{1,3}cb       | B        |
| [1234567890]db | C        |
```

And the text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, **##cb**consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum posuere ligula in diam volutpat **#cb**, vitae laoreet ligula ultrices. In quis aliquam urna, in **ab** suscipit purus. Nunc posuere efficitur **9db** nibh, tempor convallis mauris porta lobortis.

Will output the text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, **B**consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum posuere ligula in diam volutpat **B**, vitae laoreet ligula ultrices. In quis aliquam urna, in **A** suscipit purus. Nunc posuere efficitur **C** nibh, tempor convallis mauris porta lobortis.

Assuming those "regular" expressions wont overlap with each other, is there a way to implement this in c++ using `std::regex` ?

I have tried to do so, but there are two main problems:

- It will only match the very first and the very last expression.
- It will only will iterate over the text once for each expression.

Is there any way to solve this or the best solution is to program a parser for this specific purpose

Comment: You're not going to do it in a single pass with a regex, no matter what regex engine you use. You can do alternation in a regex search, but not in a replace, so you could say *if regex1 or regex2 or regex3 matches then replace with*, but you can't say *if regex1 matches replace with rep1 else if regex2 matches replace with rep2 else if regex3 matches replace with rep3* in a single pass.

Comment: I would use a *flex*-generated scanner for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As EJP says, this is trivial using (f)lex, even if you don't know anything about parser generators. (You should take a glance at flex's slightly [idiosyncratic regular expression syntax](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html), though. As with every regex-oriented tool, it has its own quirks.)

Here's a complete flex program for your task:

#### file replacer.l

```
%option noinput nounput noyywrap
%%
ab         { fputs("A", stdout); }
"#"{1,3}cb { fputs("B", stdout); }
[0-9]db    { fputs("C", stdout); }
```

The last line could have been `[1234567890]`, but `[0-9]` and `[[:digit:]]` are more idiomatic. As illustrated in the second-last line, it's normal to quote special characters by putting them inside quotation marks, something which few regex tools allow. Note that `"abc"*` is "any number of repetitions of `abc`", which is quite different from `abc*`.

The biggest limitation is that there are no captures, although that doesn't seem relevant to your question, and there are almost always simple workarounds.

To compile and run that:

```
$ flex -o replacer.c replacer.l
$ gcc -o -Wall replacer replacer.c -lfl

$ ./replacer < lorem
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Bconsectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum
posuere ligula in diam volutpat B, vitae laoreet ligula ultrices. In
quis aliquam urna, in A suscipit purus. Nunc posuere efficitur C nibh,
tempor convallis mauris porta lobortis.
```

I've been known to build quick-and-dirty tools which generate, compile and run flex programs, because the result can be a lot faster than cobbling things together from standard utilities when the input files are large. See, for example, [this answer on a companion site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137932/24557), which adds an actual `main` to the tiny flex program, in order to avoid relying on `-lfl`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware how to do this with std::regex but you could try boost::iostreams::regex_filter. The example from [their site](http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.iostreams-filters) only uses one filter but I'm sure you could tack on more. The example:

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::iostreams;

int main()
{
  char buffer[16];
  array_sink sink{buffer};
  filtering_ostream os;
  os.push(regex_filter{boost::regex{"Bo+st"}, "C++"});
  // push more filters here
  os.push(sink);
  os << "Boost" << std::flush;
  os.pop();
  std::cout.write(buffer, 3);
}
```

The caveat is that according to the docs it will read all of your text into memory at once. Your 1 million words shouldn't be a problem but for gigabyte sized files you could run into issues.

If it were me I would just do the replacement by hand since it's probably not that complex.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do.

Let r1, r2, ..., rn be your regular expressions, and r be their alternation (r1)|(r2)|...|(rn).

1. Find the first occurence of r.
2. Compare the occurence separately with r1, r2, ..., rn. When found a match, write to the destination text everything before the first occurence, and the replacement.
3. Repeat with the rest of the text.

Comment: This is not 'just one iteration'. It is *O(N^2)**.

Comment: Unless by "N" you mean something else than the length of the text, it is not true. The time complexity is O(N). And yes, this is just one iteration.